# What's the word (adjective) for a person who's good at lying, deception, manipulation, politics?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I can think of *cunning, devious, machiavellian* – but none of those is exactly what I want. I’m wondering if there’s some other word I’m failing to think of.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [conniving](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/conniving)?

It means, per Lexico/Oxford:

> Given to or involved in conspiring to do something immoral, illegal,
> or harmful.

Apparently this word at some point in the past had a more passive meaning than it has today, suggesting merely going along with a pre-existing plan, as suggested in a comment below and explained in a usage note for "connive" in [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conniving).  I've never in my life (in the U.S.) heard or seen it used this way.

Comment: Would love an explanation for this downvote.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted but the reason might have been that conniving is a bit passive - going along with things - and so only a specific subset of the wider attributes the question is asking about.

Comment: Interesting theory.  This isn't how the word is used any more.  Will update.

Comment: Here is a recent example of an article which uses the more passive meaning https://www.cbsnews.com/news/wheres-tough-britain-when-you-need-her/ The word is often used when saying that someone should aspire to higher standards - i.e. not just avoid actually doing bad things but make a stand and do not stand by and let others do bad things.

Comment: @Nemo: Ah - excellent.  I should add that I'm in the U.S.... I assume you're located elsewhere if you're acquainted with this use (assuming you had heard it used this way before digging up this quote)?  I see that this quote comes from a prominent Tory who learned English in elite British institutions in the first half of the 20th century.

Comment: I am located in Britain and the word is still used here precisely because it conveys a very specific idea - of encouraging by inaction when you could do otherwise. In fact if you read the whole article you will see that this very idea is the main theme of the article. The article was published in US media in 2007, aimed at a US audience, by a US writer who evidently though his readers would understand,

Comment: No doubt that a U.S. audience can understand the article, despite the word appearing that once, and the gist of the quote is clear enough from the context, but even the high-brow readers of the National Review, where this article evidently first appeared, would probably be somewhat jarred by the use of the word there, and would probably think something like, "I guess that's just the way British people talk!"

Answer (score 1):

**crafty**, as per [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/crafty):

> clever at attaining one's ends by indirect and often deceptive means

Answer (score 0):

A perfect adjective describing this type of behaviour is "*calculating*".

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/calculating?q=calculating)) **calculating** adjective  BrE /ˈkælkjuleɪtɪŋ/  AmE /ˈkælkjuleɪtɪŋ/ (disapproving)
> ​good at planning things so that you have an advantage, without caring about other people
> ♦  a cold and calculating killer
> ♦ I never realized you could be so calculating.
> ♦ She caught a coolly calculating glint in the other woman’s eye.

Answer (score 0):

Not an adjective, but a noun, **"demagogue"** fits a political context perfectly.

> "a person, especially a political leader, who gains power by arousing people's emotions and prejudices. [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/demagogue)

or are you looking for **"crafty"**?

> (adjective) "Skilled in underhandedness, deviousness, or deception. [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/crafty)

Answer (score 0):

My offering is someone who is **scheming**, and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/schemer) has

> **schemer**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A person who is involved in making secret or underhand plans.
>
> *Macbeth is a schemer and plotter who is eventually undone by his own misdeeds.*

Answer (score 0):

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/7-words-for-lying/mendacious) thinks that

> Probably the best fancy way to describe a liar is ***mendacious***. It comes from the Latin word *mendax*, meaning “*lying*” or “*false*.” It is often used to refer to people who habitually lie.

More specifically, the definition is

> given to or characterized by deception or falsehood or divergence from absolute truth ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mendacious))

I must say I also like ***dissembler***, which, though somewhat dated, seems to pick up in our century:

> a person who professes beliefs and opinions that he or she does not hold in order to conceal his or her real feelings or motives ([FreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dissembler))

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissemble) defines the verb to *dissemble* as:

> to put on a false appearance : conceal facts, intentions, or feelings under some pretense

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ***duplicitous*** - someone who acts in two ways at different times, openly and secretly; often including  deceitfulness and double-dealing. (OED)